# Rails 3.0.x and capistrano - No javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have a rails app that I am deploying via capistrano. The app deploys fine, however javascript is not loading. If I view source on the index page and click on

`<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1336592048" type="text/javascript"></script>`

the subsequent page includes...

`<p><pre>No route matches &quot;/javascripts/application.js&quot;</pre></p>`

Everything works great in development and I think the issue is the folder structure on the server. I tried adding

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root rails
```

but nginx just spins its wheels when loading the page and eventually times out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false
```

In deploy.rb

Comment: mmmm just noticed it was rails 3.0.x
might be a static_asset issue. Try- 
"config.serve_static_assets = true" in config/environments/production.rb. If true, change to false.

Comment: I edited you answer above. Please approve for others benefit.